# Instância declarada na variável que logo em seguida recebe um novo valor

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho o seguinte código:

```php
$config = new \Skreth\System\Config(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/config.ini');
$config = $config->getProperties();
```

Crio uma instância declarada na variável `$config` e logo em seguida a lhe dou um novo valor que é pra receber um objeto. As minhas dúvidas são:

- É correto fazer isso, pode causar algum tipo de problema?
- Existe outra maneira mais prática de fazer algo semelhante?
- É possível eu retornar valores em instâncias de classes além de string com o *__toString*?

> Edição

Como posso fazer o mesmo com este?:

```php
$SE_lang = $conn->prepare('SELECT Language FROM Language');
$SE_lang->execute();
$SA_lang = $SE_lang->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

É possível simplificá-lo? A maioria das vezes crio variáveis `$SE_...` inúteis por conta disso, tentei aplicar o exemplo da reposta, mas não consegui!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> É correto fazer isso, pode causar algum tipo de problema?

Bem, creio que isso depende muito de opinião, mas se quiser ouvir a minha, então aí vai.

Mas a principio, não tem problemas. Você está apenas sobrescrevendo um valor de uma variável.

Por questão de legibilidade, creio que cada variável deve "significar" alguma coisa. No seu caso, `$config = new Config` ao meu ver faz todo sentido, já que o nome da classe tem relação com o nome da variável. 
Porém, ao você declarar `$config = $config->getProperties()` perde um pouco de sentido, pois a final, você vai chamar de "configuração" as propriedades da configuração?

Então, ao meu ver faria mais sentido:

```
$config = new \Skreth\System\Config(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/config.ini');
$properties = $config->getProperties();
```

Vale lembrar que essa é a minha opinião, mas usar o bom senso é algo que é bom todas as pessoas aplicarem. Se você pensar que outra pessoa (caso esteja trabalhando em conjunto) vai ter que entender o seu código, então você vai ter que se preocupar também com a legibilidade.

> Existe outra maneira mais prática de fazer algo semelhante?

Se esse "mais prático" significar "simplificar a sentença", sim, existe. E claro, isso vai depender da versão do PHP que você está usando.

Por exemplo, se você quer apenas acessar o método `Config::getProperties()`, sem ter que utilizar uma variável para armazenar a instância de config (levando em consideração que você nem vai usar outros método, mas apenas o que é invocado a seguir), você poderia fazer assim:

```
   use \Skreth\System\Config;

   $properties = (new Config((dirname(__DIR__) . '/config/config.ini'))->getProperties();
```

Assim, você simplifica a chamada de `getProperties`, sem ter que armazenar a instância numa variável para depois chamar outro método.

**Nota**: Observe que eu usei o `use`, para simplificar a utilização de `Config`.

Essa funcionalidade se chama `Class member access on instantiation` e está disponível a partir do PHP  5.4.

> É possível eu retornar valores em instâncias de classes além de string com o `__toString`?

Sim, e você não imagina quantas maneiras o PHP tem de resolver isso!

Você pode usar os métodos mágicos `__get` ou `__set`, além de também poder usar a interface mágica `ArrayAccess`, que permite você prover uma interface para sua classe, onde você pode acessar os dados como se estivesse manipulando um `array`.

Vou dar alguns exemplos.

Exemplo da implementação de `ArrayAccess`. Você precisa definir 4 métodos, que representa a definição, obtenção, exclusão e verificação dos dados, como se fosse um `array`.

```
use Skreth\System\Config as BaseConfig;

class Config extends BaseConfig implements ArrayAccess
{
    public function offsetGet($key)     
    {
        return isset($this->props[$key]) ? $this->props[$key] : null;
    }

    public function offsetSet($key, $value)
    {
        $this->props[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetExists($key)
    {
        return isset($this->props[$key]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($key)
    {
        unset($this->props[$key]);
    }
}

$config = new Config('file.ini');

var_dump($config['db']); // chama offsetGet

var_dump(isset($config['db']); // chama offsetExists

$config['db'] = [/**...**/]; // chama offsetSet

unset($config['db']); // Chama offsetUnset
```

Exemplo com métodos mágicos `__set` e `__get`. Utilizei também `__unset` e `__isset`, para ficar semelhante ao exemplo acima:

```
use Skreth\System\Config as BaseConfig;

class Config extends BaseConfig implements ArrayAccess
{

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->props[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return isset($this->props[$key]) ? $this->props[$key] : null;
    }

    public function __isset($key)
    {
        return isset($this->props[$key]);
    }

    public function __unset($key)
    {
        unset($this->props[$key]);
    }
}



$config = new Config('file.ini');

var_dump($config->db); // chama __get

var_dump(isset($config->db)); // chama __isset

$config->db = [/**...**/]; // chama __set

unset($config->db); // Chama __unset
```

Agora,   se a  pergunta sobre o `__toString` estiver relacionado a diferentes retornos de tipos (como por exemplo um `__toArray`), não, ainda não temos isso em php.

Comment: É bom eu adicionar no PHPDoc da classe por exemplo `@property array db`?

Comment: @ViníciusLima sempre é bom documentar. Até mesmo porque, dependendo da implementação, você vai querer que apenas um tipo de dados seja aceito na entrada.

Comment: Como posso fazer algo semelhante com consultas da classe PDO? é possível, adicionei a pergunta :D